# Scaling of horizon chart on R

Tags: r, charts, visualization

I have just started to learn R and I have created a horizon chart using R.

However, the axes are not appearing properly. Is there any way which I could make the chart bigger and easier to see?

This is the chart I created using `horizonplot` from the latticeExtra package.:
[image]

```
require(latticeExtra)

horizonplot(data, horizonscale = 10, colorkey = TRUE, layout = c(1, 27))
```

Thanks in advance for any help given!